# How to maintain the state of AuthenticationStateProvider in Blazor server mode when refreshing the page?

Tags: authentication, blazor

How to maintain the state of AuthenticationStateProvider in Blazor server mode when refreshing the page?

The status is cleared when I refresh the browser page and I need to log in again. I hope to keep the status and not be logged out.

Comment: Are you using custom AuthenticationStateProvider?

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh (or open a new tab), it's a new "session" on the server, and Blazor does not know that you're "you".

The easiest in my opinion, is to store some authorization-data on the client, either in a cookie or in for example the local storage. When the user refreshes, you read the cookie/local storage data, and look it up in your data storage (or perhaps some caching solution)..? I store the user GUID and a session GUID on the client, which I match to our backend (SQL).